# Using mklink /h results in "Access is denied."

Tags: windows, ntfs, hardlink, mklink

From command prompt with *Administrator* privilages:

```
c:\>mklink /h c:\dirA c:\Users\Piotr\dirB
Access is denied.
```

I'm on Vista x64. Using `/j` or `/d` instead of `/h` works. What's the problem?

Related:

[Access is denied error, when I mklink on Windows 7.](https://superuser.com/questions/193632/)

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're after, but I tried mklink w/o any flags to try to link a directory and it didn't give me what I wanted.  I tried using the \D flag and that seemed to work (not sure if that's different than \d or the default, which some ms docs said was 'symbolic').

Answer (score 58, accepted):

**Hard links can only be used for files, not directories.**

References: 
[MSDN: Hard Links and Junctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365006%28VS.85%29.aspx), [<1>](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-symlinks-in-windows-vista/), and [<2>](http://www.maxi-pedia.com/difference+between+symbolic+link+and+hard+link)

Comment: "*Access is denied.*"... Not the most helpful error message here.

Comment: @P-Gn Just the usual Windows error message...

Answer (score 16):

You can use the `/j` switch to create a directory soft link. Be careful with the `del` command. To remove link to directory use the `rmdir` command, as `del` will delete all files in the directory the link points to.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue: check that the file or folder that you are trying to create **doesn't already exist**  (c:\dirA).

Comment: Folder `c:\dirA` does not exist.

Comment: OK, in this case, it's probably because it's being created on the root of c:\, see if creating it in another directory helps?

Comment: I see nothing special about c:\ in this case.

Comment: Permissions on the root of the drive (C:\) are slightly different to normal user folders, as it's a sort of "system" area in windows.

Comment: @DaviddCeFreitas No, it is not. There is no such thing as a hard link to a directory. There is no fix for "Access Denied" message when `/h` switch is used. The access permissions has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @DaviddCeFreitas As *There is no fix for "Access Denied" message when /h switch is used.* comment is true I would suggest deleting this answer.